# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when testing NotificationDemo of kaa sandbox on Raspberry PI3

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, coredump, kaa

I am trying the C SDK generated by Kaa sandbox 0.10.0 running on an AWS AMI, following the steps documented by http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Raspberry+Pi.

My RPI3 is running

pi@raspberrypi:~/kaa/NotificationDemo/CNotificationDemo $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

When running ./build.sh deploy, I got core dump after the app was started:

[100%] Linking C executable demo_client
[100%] Built target demo_client
Notification demo started
Topic list was updated
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

There were a few compilation warnings, such as

/home/pi/kaa/NotificationDemo/CNotificationDemo/libs/kaa/src/kaa/kaa_defaults.h:82:75: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]
 static const char KAA_CONFIGURATION_DATA[KAA_CONFIGURATION_DATA_LENGTH] = {};

/home/pi/kaa/NotificationDemo/CNotificationDemo/libs/kaa/src/kaa/gen/kaa_logging_gen.c:47:76: warning: unused parameter ‘reader’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 kaa_logging_empty_data_t *kaa_logging_empty_data_deserialize(avro_reader_t reader)

The complete build/deploy log is attached.

I am primarily a java guy, so could have missed something obvious for running C on RPI3. The reason I want to use C on RPI3 is that I heard jvm is not stable when reading real time sensor data from GPIO.

Thanks

James

Comment: the log file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/mf3zhhrd95e96uv/buildlog.txt?dl=0

Comment: I tried another sandbox app DataCollectionDemo. It ran on my RPI3 with C SDK. No core dump. If it proofs that my RPI3 is configured properly, then it probably means that the NotificationDemo C SDK has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the described issue was fixed in scope of [this ticket](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/APP-476)
I recommend you to get the latest Kaa Sandbox from official Kaa website or apply the [patch](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/pull/499/files) manually.